# Is it possible to display a monitor input source image in a separate window w/o switching the whole monitor to that source?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a PC with 2 monitors, a GPU that supports HDMI, DVI and DP, a CCTV system that supports VGA and HDMI, and a TV tuner that supports HDMI. I want to plug each of the sources into one of the monitors, primarily they are used to display signal from the PC, but I'd like to be able to see each other possible source's signal as well while using my PC. I know I can switch between sources manually by accessing a monitor's menu, but it's inconvenient as I lose at least a part of my PC desktop at the same time and it takes time for a monitor to switch which adds up. Is there software that can receive and display a signal from a monitor's inputs in a window? I can't even Google it as I unable to come up with a relevant search term, and all my searches only find completely irrelevant things.

I use Windows 10 but Linux-specific software is also accepted as I plan to switch to it eventually in a dual boot setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some monitors support hardware "Picture in Picture" or "Picture by Picture" mode that can show 2 inputs simultaneously. PiP shows the second input as a window, PbP shows them side by side (each taking one half of the screen).

The only other way would be to have hardware capture cards that can capture the input of the other sources on your PC.

Either way, just a piece of software to do this does not exist, as it cant magicly read the other inputs.